# Confusion over parsing looping json with jQuery

Tags: jquery, json

Just wondering if some one can help me with some a issue I am having parsing json data. I will start with a spinet of the JSON i won't include all of it (JSON is also valid) :

```
"X_bizCardServiceLinks": [
    {
        "name": "blogs",
        "js_eval": "generalrs.label_personcard_blogslink",
        "href": "https:\/\/dc3-epag-03.tm-gnet.com\/blogs\/roller-ui\/blog\/dbb8fac0-42e4-102e-9409-b38b9530f95e"
    },
    {
        "name": "quickr",
        "js_eval": "generalrs.label_personcard_quickrlink",
        "href": "https:\/\/dc3-epag-03.tm-gnet.com\/quickr\/allfiles\/people\/Jonathan.Popoola@trinitymirror.com"
    },
    {
        "name": "profiles",
        "js_eval": "generalrs.label_personcard_profilelink",
        "href": "https:\/\/dc3-epag-03.tm-gnet.com\/profiles\/html\/simpleSearch.do?searchFor=dbb8fac0-42e4-102e-9409-b38b9530f95e&searchBy=userid"
    },
    {
        "name": "activities",
        "js_eval": "generalrs.label_personcard_activitieslink",
        "href": "https:\/\/dc3-epag-03.tm-gnet.com\/activities\/service\/html\/mainpage#dashboard%2Cmyactivities%2Cuserid%3Ddbb8fac0-42e4-102e-9409-b38b9530f95e%2Cname%3DJonathan Popoola"
    },
    {
        "name": "dogear",
        "js_eval": "generalrs.label_personcard_dogearlink",
        "href": "https:\/\/dc3-epag-03.tm-gnet.com\/dogear\/html?userid=dbb8fac0-42e4-102e-9409-b38b9530f95e"
    },
    {
        "name": "communities",
        "js_eval": "generalrs.label_personcard_communitieslink",
        "href": "https:\/\/dc3-epag-03.tm-gnet.com\/communities\/service\/html\/allcommunities?userid=dbb8fac0-42e4-102e-9409-b38b9530f95e"
    },
    {
        "name": "wikis",
        "js_eval": "generalrs.label.personcard.wikislink",
        "href": "https:\/\/dc3-epag-03.tm-gnet.com\/wikis\/home\/search?uid=dbb8fac0-42e4-102e-9409-b38b9530f95e&name=Jonathan Popoola"
    },
    {
        "name": "files",
        "js_eval": "generalrs.label_personcard_fileslink",
        "href": "https:\/\/dc3-epag-03.tm-gnet.com\/files\/app\/person\/dbb8fac0-42e4-102e-9409-b38b9530f95e"
    }
],
```

What I need to do is access each child element of the "X_bizCardServiceLinks" and store the name and href to a variable - I am able to return all of the individual children but not target each child separately - I am using the following code :

```
$.each(response.X_bizCardServiceLinks, function(){
            $.each(this, function(n, v){
                var random = n;
                var anotherRandom = v;
                console.log(v); 
                //$("#linkTable tr").append("<td><a href=\""+ this.href +"\">"+ this.name +"</a>");
            });

        });
```

Response is the JSON but stored, any help would be greatly appreciated thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying much too hard

```
$.each(response.X_bizCardServiceLinks, function(){
    var name = this.name;
    var href = this.href;            
    console.log(name, href);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/F8XPM/

Comment: thank you very much will give it a whirl and let u know the result

Comment: Thanks Squeegy that worked a treat :-) - one quick questions i need to append the first 5 elements to 1 div and the other to another div - I can only think of crude ways to do - would you have an idea what would be best practice. thanks

Comment: Keep a count and do some at, or until, that count becomes 5.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.each(response.X_bizCardServiceLinks, function(index, elem) {
    // elem.name
    // elem.href
});

'"X_bizCardServiceLinks": []'
```

Looks like invalid JSON anyways. It should be enclosed in `{ }`:

```
'{"X_bizCardServiceLinks": []}'
```

Comment: i hav'nt added all of the json just a snipet  - to make the post more readable

Answer (score 0):

You’re using a callback function to be called for each element with the each function. Unfortunately you did not specify a parameter, which can be used to access the individual element in the callback function.

So instead of
    $.each(response.X_bizCardServiceLinks, function(){
you would use
    $.each(response.X_bizCardServiceLinks, function(index, el){
and could then get the child elements with `el.name` and `el.href`.

See the jQuery API for the each function at http://api.jquery.com/each/

```
$.each(response.X_bizCardServiceLinks, function(index, el){
    $.each(this, function(n, v){
        $("#linkTable tr").append("<td><a href=\""+ el.href +"\">"+ el.name +"</a>");
    });
});
```

Comment: thank you I will give it a whirl and let you know the result :-)